# Changing CSS files in Magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento-2.1, css, less

Currently trying to change the **top menu background color**, tried to change it from the **CSS** files, found out through firebug that the file `pub/static/frontend/Venustheme/beat/en_US/css/styles-l.css` is the one responsible for this,

And even tried to change it on firebug to confirm, turns out it actually is.

So I changed the `css` file and refreshed the page, but nothing changed, looked up solutions for this, flushed cache storage flushed Magento cache and flushed `javascript/css` cache through the admin interface, didn't work,

Checked the URL in `core_config_data` turned out to be correct, can anyone help with this? and is there a way to change the `css` files through the admin interface?

Also, what is the difference between beat and beat_child?

and does the less file affect that in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to compile LESS if you aren't already, the easiest way is to enable client-side compilation. Login to the admin and navigate to `store > config > advanced > developer > front-end workflow` and set it to `client-side compilation` (or something similar).

Then delete these two directories:

```
var/view_preprocessed
pub/static/frontend
```

Clear your caches (Magento and browser) then refresh. Your change should now be displayed.

**Note: There are better ways of compiling such as Grunt/Gulp but that's out of scope for this answer.**

Answer (score 1):

Never work on Pub/Static/frontend folder directly.
It's get generated automatically.

CSS and JS files for theme can be found in app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/web folder.